# Cannot open samba share in file manager but can mount it using CLI

Tags: docker, samba, nautilus, file-sharing

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my machine where I am trying to run docker container (ubuntu based) with samba.

The container is running in a background. I can mount shared folder to host OS using

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=sambakot,uid=kot,gid=kot //127.17.0.2/sambashare ~/tests/myFolderToMount/
```

But if I try to access samba share via default file manager using "Other Locations" then nothing happens as I input user credentials. There is no error message, just nothing happens as I click "connect". The window continues to be clickable, I can click connect again but still nothing happens.

Host machine has one user except *root* - *kot*

Docker container has *root* and *sambakot* as users

smb.conf contains (I removed all commented lines, it's just a default config, only last sambashare part was added)

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[sambashare]
    path = /dirToMount
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
```

Permissions for /dirToMount inside docker container look this way:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 sambakot sambakot 4096 Feb  6 18:51 dirToMount/
```

What am I doing wrong when using file manager?

Not sure if it's important but I assume that everything is ok with network connection (port forwarding)

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND          CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                       NAMES
183e3f525ae2   sambav6   "/bin/bash -p"   37 minutes ago   Up 37 minutes   0.0.0.0:139->139/tcp, :::139->139/tcp, 137-138/udp, 0.0.0.0:445->445/tcp, :::445->445/tcp   friendly_chebyshev
```